# Is there a javascript function for finding the orderings of a group of things

Tags: javascript, permutation, combinatorics

For example, is there a function that can order the letters ABCD in 4! ways and output their different arrangements. If not, what is an efficient way to code such a function?

Comment: Easiest way to code something like this is to use recursion.

Comment: Could you show me how to that, with a small case like 3!